# How to specify column mappings in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a legacy DB and I'm building a Rails application on top of it. My `Orders` table has a column `extraCharges`. When I try to access it, I get an error `NoMethodError`:

**index.html.erb**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Order id</th>
    <th>Extra charges</th>
  </tr>

  <% @orders.each do |order| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= order.id %></td>
        <td><%= order.extraCharges %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>

</table>
```

`undefined method 'extraCharges' for nil:NilClass`

I suppose because `extraCharges` doesn't comply with [Rails' naming conventions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html). But in those conventions, it's not said how to specify column mappings.

How is this done?

Comment: How's `@orders` defined in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@orders` variable includes `nil`. For example, use `#compact` to drop nils.